# Windows 10 reset and OneDrive

Tags: data-recovery, windows-10, onedrive

I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I noticed that the performance is not the best overall (I haven't formatted my laptop in a while now). Therefore I'd like to "factory reset" Windows (by going to Settings > Update & security > Reset this PC > Get started > Remove Everything - as described in http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

I have almost all of my personal files backed up in OneDrive. It may seem like a stupid question since I'm 90% sure that reseting my Windows wouldn't delete my files stored there, but I'd like to make sure before doing anything stupid. Has anyone performed the mentioned steps and checked if the OneDrive files and folders remain there even after restoring?

Comment: You are not going to be online when you do a format, so the client,, wouldn't be able to push any updates to your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No. Your files will not be deleted.

### Why?

When factory resetting Windows nothing but core Windows Services (if any at all, really) are running. The OneDrive sync service doesn't run at all. This means that nothing on the "placeholder" files, and physical files, will be pushed to the server. I did this awhile back and everything was fine.

For extra assurance, your machine won't be online. Therefore even if the Sync service was running-- it wouldn't be able to push anything online.